# Who needs clean configuration? Swapping server.xml

Tags: file-system, bash

So I'm working on a project that sometimes requires me to switch my server configuration. This is due to some circumstances with database drivers and names that are "too expensive to fix" ...

That made me think though: "Why do I always copy these files around manually?"

I decided I won't and wrote this small script to help me:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 1 ]
    then 
    echo "you must provide a configuration to switch to"
    exit
fi;

if [ -a $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server_$1.xml ]
    then
    rm $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml
    cp $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server_$1.xml $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml
else
    echo "given configuration was not found. did not make any changes."
fi;

exit 0
```

Usage is dead simple: I made this available system-wide and can just call:

```
switch-config postgres
```

or

```
switch-config firebird
```

To make changes happen.

This is built for my personal convenience, so please ignore the incredibly bad error messages, also the (nonexistent) directory structure is for simple convenience. Comments like "move the different configurations somewhere else" don't help me.

In any case, what can I improve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Method

I'd suggest, instead of `rm`-ing and `cp`-ing, keeping each configuration set as named and symlinking to them as needed.

This gives you a couple of benefits:

- You can tell which the current one is without opening the file, just using `ls -l`:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 user group 4 Jul 29 07:12 server.xml -> config-for-blah.xml`

- Changes are (sort-of) atomic: `rm` and `cp` take time, while over-writing a symlink with a symlink is as close to instant as you can reasonably make it.
- You can move the actual files anywhere later and just update the symlinks: version-control it in a repo directory, put configuration sets into separate directories, whatever.

Replacing the `rm` and `cp` in your current script, that'd be:

```
ln -sf "$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server_$1.xml" "$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml"
```

(You need `-f`, or else `ln` will complain that the link you're trying to create already exists.)

You should also detect whether the main commands have completed successfully, probably using something like:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
    then
    echo "Oops." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

#### Scripting

- Quote your filenames. This helps avoid accidents where variables are mis-set.
- Check your test types. In `[ $# != 1 ]`, `$#` is being referenced as a number, but `!=` is for strings. Use `-ne` for numbers. (This is just a good habit to get into.)
- You don't need the semicolons after the `fi`.
- Error messages should usually go to `stderr`: `echo "Error" >&2`
- When detecting an error and exiting, exit with an status other than 0: this lets you easily detect problems when using the script. (c.f. the check in the method section above.)
- Maybe do something to avoid command aliases. Sometimes aliases for commands like `rm`, `cp`, and `ln` can get into scripts by accident and make scripts break. You can avoid this by making sure your use of them doesn't trigger alias expansion for the commands, either by quoting, escaping, or using the full path.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Aesin, definitely using symlinks will be much better.

A few minor points on top of his review:

- Your script is not using any Bash features. You could as well change the shebang to `#!/bin/sh`
- An alternative way to validate the command line arguments: `if [ ! "$1" ]`. I often prefer this, as it also checks that the argument is non-empty.
- When the command line arguments are invalid, the common exit code is 2
- There's no need for the `exit 0` at the end of the script

Lastly, the `then` clauses are a bit oddly placed.
The common placement is either this way:

```
if [ ... ]; then
```

Or this way:

```
if [ ... ]
then
```

Comment: actually.. `-a` seems to be a bash feature. Switching the shebang to `#!/bin/sh` results in "Unexpected operator -a"

Comment: Oh. Come to think of it, I'm not used to seeing `-a`. I think you can replace it with `-f`, which will do the same and work in non-Bash too.

Comment: yep that works just fine :)